# How to post variable from field in page 1 to page 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

My code is trying to allow user to add new text field by clicking the add button. I want to post all the text fields the user had added (be it 2, 3, 4 or more) to the next page so I can retrieve the data that the user had entered.

P/S: Added new requirement: Retrieve data and **print the data** that the user had entered.

Here is my code:

```
    <html> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 2;
        $("#addMenuTab").click(function () {
            if(counter>10){
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
            }   

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Menu Tab #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
                '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeMenuTab").click(function () {
            if(counter==1){
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }   
            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        });

    });
    </script>
    <form name="basicInfo" action="contents.php" method="post"> 
    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
                            <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                                <label>Menu Tab #1 : </label>
                                <input type='text' id='textbox1' >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                            <input type='button' value='  Add Menu Tab  ' id='addMenuTab' />
                            <input type='button' value='  Remove Menu Tab  ' id='removeMenuTab' />
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if PHP - use session, if JS - use local storage

Comment: use Ajax instead of using different pages

Comment: can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all these fields and their values on contents.php under $_POST global array. 
For example:

```
<?php 
    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_R($_POST); 
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: s it possible for me to retrieve the input using something like $_POST['xxx']; ? I do not what to put in the 'xxx' as its a count loop that i coded.

Also, i wanted to print out the data the user entered. print out not in terms of array but each individual entry from the user in the field input.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for your problem.
Use one counter to count the number of textfields. 
We can later pass this variable to html.
Modify your javascript:-

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    $("#count").val(counter-1); 
    $("#addMenuTab").click(function () {
        if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Menu Tab #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
            '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        $("#count").val(counter); 
        counter++;                    
    });

    $("#removeMenuTab").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        $("#count").val(counter-1); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Now add one hidden field in your html form. The value of this hidden field will be the total number of texfields.

```
<input type='hidden' id='count' name='counter' value=''/>
```

In your contents.php add the below given code.

```
$count=$_POST['counter'];
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
 echo "value from textbox$i is".$_POST["textbox$i"]."<br/>";
}
```

Here you will get the total number of textfields in the variable **$count**
Since the name of your texfields are like textbox1,textbox2..etc You can use a loop for getting all the data from your previous page using the  **POST** method.

Also add name attribute to your initial textbox to get this work.

```
<input type='text' id='textbox1' name="textbox1" >
```

Answer (score -1):

I don' understand what is your question. If you add some inputs like textbox10, you will be able to read textbox10 without problems on your server.

Comment: This does not seem to me as answer.

Comment: Yes. can read textbox10 without problems. but i would like to print out the input that the user key in.

its something like $_POST['']; but i'm not sure what to input in the ''.